# How to execute a callback function after all tasks were completed？

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I use the following code:

```
grunt.task.options({
    done: function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('build success');
    }
});
```

but not working，hope your help, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 7):

Why not create a task to print the message and adding this task at the end. Like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('done', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln('build success"');
});
grunt.registerTask('default', ['yourTask1', 'yourTask2', 'done']);
```

Comment: +1 since grunt tasks are synchronous.  The last task will be executed only if previous ones are executed without error